# Java API for Growl

Tags: growl

Growl has a network protocol to received notifications from other apps.

It seems that the jitsi project (aka SIP Communicator) uses these types of notfication but refers to a library called growl4j probably developed during Google Summer of Code 2009.

However, this library does not seem to exist anymore? Some traces found on google related to growl4j.dev.java.net, but the site does not exist anymore.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 4):

Here are links to a couple of Growl Java libraries:

http://code.google.com/p/jgntp/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/libgrowl/

Both of these are based on the new GNTP protocol so they work with the newest versions of Growl (1.3+ from the Mac App Store).

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Brian, 
the two quoted libraries are the only ones around I think, which work with the latest growl versions.

Here is an example:
http://blog.growlforwindows.com/2009/04/new-java-growlgntp-library-available.html

Simple enough:

```
// connect to Growl on the given host
GrowlConnector growl = new GrowlConnector("hostname");

// give your application a name and icon (optionally)
Application downloadApp = new Application("Downloader", "http://example.com/icon.png");

// create reusable notification types, their names are used in the Growl settings
NotificationType downloadStarted = new NotificationType("Download started",     "c:\started.png");
NotificationType downloadFinished = new NotificationType("Download finished",     "c:\finished.jpg");
NotificationType[] notificationTypes = new NotificationType[] { downloadStarted,   downloadFinished };

// now register the application in growl
growl.register(downloadApp, notificationTypes);

// create a notification with specific title and message
Notification ubuntuDownload = new Notification(downloadApp, downloadStarted, "Ubuntu  9.4", "654 MB");

// finally send the notification
growl.notify(ubuntuDownload);
```